# Barcode scanning doesn't work if barcode reader app not installed

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner, android-vision

i am trying to make an application that will work on the phone to scan bar code. so i have tried the code bellow  but it gives me this error

```
11-28 11:18:45.750: E/AndroidRuntime(772): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 11:18:45.750: E/AndroidRuntime(772): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN (has extras) }
11-28 11:18:45.750: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
```

i am still trying this using emulator and external camera on my laptop. so can you please help me

here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        HandleClick hc = new HandleClick();
        findViewById(R.id.butQR).setOnClickListener(hc);
        findViewById(R.id.butProd).setOnClickListener(hc);
        findViewById(R.id.butOther).setOnClickListener(hc);
      }
      private class HandleClick implements OnClickListener{
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
          switch(arg0.getId()){
            case R.id.butQR:
              intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            break;
            case R.id.butProd:
              intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
            break;
            case R.id.butOther:
              intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR");
            break;
          }
          startActivityForResult(intent, 0);    //Barcode Scanner to scan for us
        }
      }
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
          TextView tvStatus=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
          TextView tvResult=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            tvStatus.setText(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT"));
            tvResult.setText(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
          } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            tvStatus.setText("Press a button to start a scan.");
            tvResult.setText("Scan cancelled.");
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sdk.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        >
        <activity
            android:name="sdk.example.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app to read bar code is not installed on you phone first install this app first.

[click here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.androidtest&hl=en)

Comment: It is also possible to just include the Zxing barcode.jar in the application, then you dont need to prompt your users to download the scanner app

Comment: @Flexo it is not a recommend way!

Comment: It might not be the recommended way, but if his project wants to go that way because it makes sense for them they should also know that it is an option.

Comment: @Flexo is it possible to install the app on my laptop to be able to test it before installing it on phone?

Comment: @Flexo you may be intall this app on [Bluestack](http://bluestacks.com/) application if your laptop has camera :)

Answer (score 0):

you need use [ScanningViaIntent](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent) it handles all the things. Very well :)